# webpack - using DefinePlugin for SCSS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass

I need to make my environment variables available to my [S]CSS files like it's done for the JS files using `DefinePlugin`. Something like this:

```
/** webpack.config.js **/
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        IMAGES_FOLDER: JSON.stringify('img')
    })
  ]
```

```
/** index.scss **/
html {
    background: url(../IMAGES_FOLDER/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure that's possible, wouldn't webpack fileloader be an option ? 
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: @Gus Costa did you find a way to do the replace in scss?